# If $a,b,c$ are distinct positive real numbers and $a^2+b^2+c^2=1$, then prove $ab+bc + ac$ will be less than 1.

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratics, symmetric-polynomials

$$(a+b+c)^2-2(ab+bc +ac)=1$$
$$ab+bc + ac=\frac{(a+b+c)^2-1}{2}$$
Which shows that it can take any positive real value. Is there anything else that needs to be added to get the answer?

Comment: As you say: it still looks like  that it can take any positive real value, and perhaps even some negative values between -1/2 and 0. So what is missing from your answer is an argument that it cannot exceed 1, i.e. that $(a + b + c)^2$ cannot exceed 3

Comment: There is no such condition specified. I have a solution which answers it satisfactorily, but I want to know what’s wrong with my solution

Comment: Well just that. The question in the title says that $ab + bc + ac$ should be less than 1 but it is not clear at all from your last expression that that is the case. What if a + b + c = 9? Then your formula gives ab + bc + ac = 40 which clearly is bigger than 1. So what is missing from your solution is some argument that $a + b + c = 9$ can not happen. And similar for $a + b + c = 2$ etc etc etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your question is "what is wrong with my answer" rather than "how do I get the correct answer" which I think you already know.

In one sense, there is nothing wrong with your answer of  $$ab+bc + ac=\frac{(a+b+c)^2-1}{2}.$$  You have correctly expressed the variable quantity $ab+bc+ca$   in terms of another variable quantity.

The problem is that $\frac{(a+b+c)^2-1}{2}$ is dependent on the values of $a,b$ and $c$ which satisfy $a^2+b^2+c^2=1$ in just as complicated a way as $ab+bc+ca$.

So the idea of this type of question is to express quantities in terms of **particular** quantities (dependng on what the question is.) For this problem the best quantity would seem to be $(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2$.

Comment: So there are certain limits to to what $a+b+c$ can be, you mean to say?

Comment: That's right. You might like to show that it is less than $\sqrt3$.

Comment: Okay you lost me. How is it √3 again?

Comment: $(a+b+c)^2=3(a^2+b^2+c^2)-(a-b)^2-(b-c)^2-(c-a)^2<3$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2>0$$

Comment: Yeah, I actually have that solution with me. What’s wrong with mine?

Answer (score 1):

By the [Rearrangement inequality](https://brilliant.org/wiki/rearrangement-inequality/):
$$ab+bc+ca\le a^2+b^2+c^2=1.$$
If $a,b,c$ are mutually distinct, then the inequality will be strict.